# org-clock-report not updating current day values

Tags: org-mode, org-clock, org-clock-table

I am very recently working with time tracking in org-mode.

When I make do `org-clock-report`, it reports well.

I edited the top line to display features per date and `C-c C-c`:

```
#+BEGIN: clocktable :maxlevel 3 :scope file :step day :tstart "<-4d>" :tend "<now>" :compact t
```

So that I can see the info for the *last four days sorted by date*.

My problem is until the day finishes the stats don't add up and show. For example today is August 6th and this is what I have despite having clocked 4 + hours. It will display this properly tomorrow.:

> Daily report: [2019-08-06 di]
>
> | Headline     | Time   |
>
> |--------------+--------|
>
> | *Total time* | *0:00* |

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All that was necessary was to change to `tend "<tomorrow>"`, i.e., now to tomorrow

```
#+BEGIN: clocktable :maxlevel 3 :scope file :step day :tstart "<-4d>" :tend "<tomorrow>" :compact t
```